# In the photoelectric effect, why is the saturation current produced same for two radiations with different frequencies but same intensity?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Let's say that the two radiations have frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$, with $f_1 > f_2$. Intensity of both is same. Now we define intensity as:

$$I = nhf$$
$$I_1 = I_2$$
Therefore,
$$n_1hf_1 = n_2hf_2$$
Since $f_1 > f_2$, 
$$n_2 > n_1$$

This means the radiation with lower frequency has more *number of photons per unit area per unit time* striking the photosensitive surface. Then why is the saturation current for both the radiations same? Shouldn't it be greater for the radiation with the greater value of $n$ because more electrons will be struck by the photons?

Comment: Quantum yield depends on frequency.

Comment: agreed about frequency  dependence.see the paper<https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0006349574859278/1-s2.0-S0006349574859278-main.pdf?_tid=spdf-58190ad7-095c-4b18-9719-a96966babf28&acdnat=1519740326_55539388e7f98e68b317eb8003553cc6>